# How to add days to a datetime string?

Tags: c, datetime

I want to add N number of days to the datetime string `s`. I tried to do that by extracting year,month,day fields separately but it does not work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
int main
{
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
  char s[64];
  strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%Y-%m-%d", tm);  //gives date in yy-mm-dd format
  printf("%s",s);      //prints the date
}
```

Comment: Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime). What does it tell you is contained in the `struct tm`? You have not really extracted anything. You have just printed out in a certain format. You can't add to a "string". The components of the date are already in `tm` so use that, not the string.

Comment: how can i get the day month and year fields using  `tm` ?@kaylum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `N` days to the `tm_mday` member and then normalize with `mktime()`.
It is not practical for a direct string edit [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013271/how-to-add-days-to-a-datetime-string/43016172?noredirect=1#comment73115719_43013271).

`time_t mktime(struct tm *timeptr);` returns a `time_t` conversion of `*timeptr`, yet that value is ignored below other than to check for errors. It is the side effect that the function adjusts the members to their usual primary range that is desired.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
// next week
#define N 7

int main() {
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
  tm->tm_mday += N;
  if (mktime(tm) == -1) {
    printf("Calendar time cannot be represented.\n");
  } else {
    char s[64];
    strftime(s, sizeof s, "%Y-%m-%d", tm);
    printf("%s\n", s);  // Print the date.
  }
}
```

Output on March 25th.  Notice `tm_mday` and `tm_mon` have been adjusted.

```
2017-04-01
```